# What does a RF wave carry?

Tags: rf, ac, frequency, energy

Other than an AC (Alternating Current) can a RF wave carry anything else ? How can the energy a RF wave carry be measured ? Would the frequency of the wave be related to the transmitted energy of the wave ?

Comment: This is all pretty complicated to explain properly. It is not correct to say that an RF wave carries an AC current. Not if the wave is propagating in air or space. There is a relationship between photon wavelength and energy (Planck's constant). But a photon and a wave are really not the same thing. Basically, to measure the power of a wave, you would probably use an antenna and a receiver. The wave will excite the antenna and cause a voltage to appear at the receiver. The magnitude of the voltage will be related to the power of the wave.

Comment: If you think of a radio transmitter as a photon source, then you can calculate the energy of the photons it emits using a few simple relationships. Wavelength = C/f, where C is the speed of light, and f is frequency. E=h*f where E is the energy of the photon, h is Planck's constant and f is frequency. The number of photons emitted per second is determined by the transmit power of the wave and the energy of the photon.

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/waves/emwavecon.html

Answer (score 1):

An RF wave propagating through free space consists of a magnetic field 'waving' sideways, and an electric field 'waving' sideways at right angles to the magnetic field, both waving at right angles to the direction of travel, described as a single electromagnetic wave. You may sometimes hear the description TEM wave, which stands for Transverse Electric Magnetic.

When this wave hits an antenna, it can induce an AC voltage in it, which can cause an AC current to flow in a load connected to it.

There's no need to do ones head in with exactly what is waving, or how it 'becomes' photons when that's a more appropriate description. If you think you understand, then you probably don't, and neither do physicists whose day job is to figure out that sort of thing. I just accept I don't understand, and use whichever description is most appropriate to the measurement situation.

A reference way to measure the energy of the wave, crude though it may seem, is to absorb it in a load, and measure the temperature rise. In the case of visible light, absorbing by a black surface or better still a black body cavity would be appropriate. In the case of a radio wave, you would absorb it in a resistor connected to an antenna. A measurement absorber is called a bolometer.

Using a bolometer is not usually the most convenient way to measure the power of a wave, which is why we use photodiodes and voltmeters and suchlike. However, it is the reference way, which is the way all the more convenient techniques must be calibrated back to.

Answer (score 1):

> How can the energy a RF wave carry be measured ?

Build a dipole antenna that is correctly dimensioned to correspond to the wavelength of the RF. The dipole antenna has an area of coverage (measured in square metres) that is [0.1305\$\lambda^2\$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antenna_aperture) where lambda is the wavelength of the RF. This area of coverage is like a fishing net held up in space - energy flowing thru that net is captured by the antenna whereas energy that flows past it is not captured.

Terminate the dipole in [73 ohms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole_antenna) taking into account that the dipole should be slightly shortened to cancel out the reactive part of the antenna. Dipole length should be 143/F in metres where F is in MHz. Theoretically all the energy captured by "the net" produces power in the resistor.

Measure the voltage across the terminating resistor and calculate power. That power (plus a few losses) is captured by the aperture of the antenna and so you can calculate watts per square metre incident at the antenna.

Watts per square metre = volts per metre (E field) x amps per metre (H field). The ratio of E to H is 120\$\pi\$ or 377 ohms. This allows you to calculate E and H individually.

All bets are off if the measuring antenna is too close to the transmitting antenna - near field problems make this measurement impractical because the basic coherent EM wave cannot have formed properly. This generally means that if the distance to the transmit antenna is less than 1 wavelength measurements are definitely inaccurate.

> Would the frequency of the wave be related to the transmitted energy
> of the wave ?

Transmit energy is unrelated to frequency of transmission.